# how to cancel a scheduled command for CMD

Tags: shutdown, hibernate, scheduled-tasks

i just scheduled a hibernate command:

```
at 13:00 shutdown /h
```

Is there any command to abort this scheduled operation?

1. `shutdown /a` didn't work, it said there is no scheduled shutdown.
2. `At 12:59 shutdown /a` didn't work as well for aborting `At 13:00 shutdown /h`

Comment: Type `schtasks /?` and take it from there.

Comment: @afh `at {id} /delete` is much simpler ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill - OK. Win10 tells me that `at` is deprecated and to use `schtasks` instead.

Comment: @AFH Yes "The AT command has been deprecated and is no longer available In Windows 8." so the OP must have Windows 7 or earlier ;)

Comment: @AFH And if you want delete with `schtasks` you have to know the taskname create from the `at` command, which will be `At{id}` ...

Comment: @DavidPostill - I have upgraded all my W7/8 systems to W10, so I have no means of checking. My only remaining Windows systems are XP and Vista somewhere on a Linux laptop. Thanks for the `cmd` reference in your answer: I have used a separate search each time I need more information than `/?` gives: now I have a direct reference.

Answer (score 2):

In my case `atq` to list all pending jobs scheduled with `at`.
Sample Output:

```
atq
2   Fri May  1 06:00:00 2020 a root
1   Fri May  1 05:00:00 2020 a root
```

If you need more infor to understand whih job is which, you can run `at -c` followed by jobid to see the commands that will be executed for this job id.
For example:

```
at -c 1
#!/bin/sh
umask 22
LANG=bg_BG.UTF-8; export LANG
SUDO_GID=1000; export SUDO_GID
...
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin; export PATH
...
ls
```

(Some of the output omitted, and substituted with `...`)

and then `atrm` followed by job id to remove a certain scheduled job.
Sample (On success, there is no output):

```
atrm 1
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Is there any command to abort this scheduled operation?

```
at 13:00 shutdown /h
```

You can run `at` by itself to list the scheduled jobs. Example:

```
F:\test>at 13:00 echo "hello"
Added a new job with job ID = 1

F:\test>at
Status ID   Day                     Time          Command Line
---------------------------------------------------------------------
        1   Tomorrow                13:00         echo hello
```

This returns a list of scheduled jobs, together with an `ID` for each job.

**To delete a scheduled job:**

```
at ID /delete
```

Example:

```
F:\test>at 13:00 echo "hello"
Added a new job with job ID = 1

F:\test>at
Status ID   Day                     Time          Command Line
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1   Tomorrow                13:00         echo hello

F:\test>at 1 /delete

F:\test>at
There are no entries in the list.
```

**To delete a scheduled job using `schtasks`:**

```
schtasks /delete /tn At{ID}
```

Where `{ID}` is the ID of the `at` task.

Example:

```
F:\test>schtasks /delete /tn At1
WARNING: Are you sure you want to remove the task "At1" (Y/N)? y
SUCCESS: The scheduled task "At1" was successfully deleted.
```

**To delete *all* scheduled jobs:**

```
at /delete /yes
```

---

#### at usage

```
F:\test>at /?
The AT command schedules commands and programs to run on a computer at
a specified time and date. The Schedule service must be running to use
the AT command.

AT [\\computername] [ [id] [/DELETE] | /DELETE [/YES]]
AT [\\computername] time [/INTERACTIVE]
    [ /EVERY:date[,...] | /NEXT:date[,...]] "command"

\\computername     Specifies a remote computer. Commands are scheduled on the
                   local computer if this parameter is omitted.
id                 Is an identification number assigned to a scheduled
                   command.
/delete            Cancels a scheduled command. If id is omitted, all the
                   scheduled commands on the computer are canceled.
/yes               Used with cancel all jobs command when no further
                   confirmation is desired.
time               Specifies the time when command is to run.
/interactive       Allows the job to interact with the desktop of the user
                   who is logged on at the time the job runs.
/every:date[,...]  Runs the command on each specified day(s) of the week or
                   month. If date is omitted, the current day of the month
                   is assumed.
/next:date[,...]   Runs the specified command on the next occurrence of the
                   day (for example, next Thursday).  If date is omitted, the
                   current day of the month is assumed.
"command"          Is the Windows NT command, or batch program to be run.
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [at](http://ss64.com/nt/at.html) - Schedule a command or batch file to run on a computer at a specific date and time.

Answer (score 0):

Shutdown /a will only work after the shutdown has been schedule using the command

So wait for the shutdown event to trigger and then run shutdown /a

so if you run this at 13.01 it would work

Comment: `at {id} /delete` is much simpler ;)

Comment: It's a matter of choice I have backup scheduled daily at 5pm on my servers and then I shutdown using this command but if I am still working I just use shutdown /a to cancel it